# How do i fix a corrupted file on fallout new vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have been playing fallout new vegas for about five days. I tried to load it again but it just gives me an infinite loading  screen. my cousin said it was a corrupted file. My question is, is  there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're a binary editing guru, there is no way to fix a corrupted save. You will need to load an earlier save. If other saves display the same problem, roll back any changes you've done to your mods or try a fresh install without any mods.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you, from experience, how to recover your manual save (not your auto-save). This has happened to me several times on xbox 360. Not sure what platform you're on, but probably will work for any.

The problem is with the auto-save. It gets corrupted and somehow affects your manual save's ability to load as well. So, you need to overwrite your auto-save.

To do this, start a new game and get to the point where the game writes its first auto-save; this is right after you wake up in the doc's house.

Then, load your manual save. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Start a new game, then load your save game file. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much that can be done about the corrupted save. Just load from previous save, that usually worked for me.

I haven't figured it out 100% sure, but this seems to be related to Steam Cloud sync. To disable it, go to `Properties`, select tab `Updates` and untick checkbox for `Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for …`.

Another possibility is that it happens when you're making a save while previous save is still being written to disk. Disabling auto-saves and relying only on manual saves could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your pervious save and THEN load your corrupted save (if autosave was corrupted then make sure you don't overwrite it). Worked with me.